# How can my web application find the currently running master database?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, connection-string, mirroring, high-availability

I'd like to set up two SQL Server 2008 R2 instances with synchronous mirroring and automatic failover. If I understand this scenario correctly, the SQL servers switch roles (principal and failover) whenever a failover occurs (please let me know if I'm wrong here).

What is the standard approach to locate the current primary database from the web application? I know I can specify the two server like this in the connection string:

```
Data Source=myPrincipalServerAddress;Failover Partner=myFailoverServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True;
```

But does that also work properly if the servers are actually currently working the other way round? In other words, would this work just as well:

```
Data Source=myFailoverServerAddress;Failover Partner=myPrincipalServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True;
```

I've found an [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366348.aspx) on this subject, but it's not very explicit in this regard.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without a witness there's no automatic failover. mirroring itself is transparent to your application because it's handled internally by the ADO.net provider.

Comment: Good point about the automatic failover without witness, I was not aware of that. So, provided that I do have a witness, your answer is "yes, the second connection string also works"?

Comment: yes. it makes no difference to the ADO provider that i know of.

Comment: alo make sure that you specifiy FQDN names for the servers when setting up mirroring and not their IP addresses. there are some bugs with just IP addresses: http://is.gd/ePwD00